# How to show/hide <div> with <?php?> in it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a dropdown list which will show some divs. In the divs, I include a PHP file. When I try to show/hide a div using the dropdown list, it doesn't work. What is wrong with my code?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.report').hide();
        $('#prodi').change(function () {
            $(this).find("option").each(function () {
                $('#' + this.value).hide();
            });
            $('#' + this.value).show();

        });
      });
    </script>
```

dropdown

```
<div class="prodi ops" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
       Program Studi :
           <select id="prodi">
         <option value="">-Pilih Prodi-</option>
         <option value="D3-Teknik Informatika">D3-Teknik Informatika</option>
         <option value="Program Kompetensi">Program Kompetensi</option>
         <option value="S1-Teknik Informatika">S1-Teknik Informatika</option>
         <option value="S1-Sistem Informasi">S1-Sistem Informasi</option>
           </select>
       </div>
```

other divs

```
    <div class="report" id="S1-Teknik Informatika">
        <?php include 'searchs1if.php'; ?>
    </div>
  <div class="report" id="S1-Sistem Informasi">
    <?php include 'search_s1si.php'; ?>
  </div>
  <div class="report" id="D3-Teknik Informatika">
    <?php include 'searchd3if.php'; ?>
  </div>
  <div class="report" id="Program Kompetensi">
    <?php include 'searchprokom.php'; ?>
  </div>
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Spaces aren't allowed in IDs. When jQuery processes the selector

```
$("#S1-Teknik Informatika")
```

it looks for an element with `id="S1-Teknik"` and then looks for an `<Informatika>` tag somewhere within that element.

Get rid of the spaces in your IDs (and the corresponding values in the `<select>`, of course) and your code will work. I've replaced them with underscores below.

dropdown

```
<div class="prodi ops" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
   Program Studi :
       <select id="prodi">
     <option value="">-Pilih Prodi-</option>
     <option value="D3-Teknik_Informatika">D3-Teknik Informatika</option>
     <option value="Program_Kompetensi">Program Kompetensi</option>
     <option value="S1-Teknik_Informatika">S1-Teknik Informatika</option>
     <option value="S1-Sistem_Informasi">S1-Sistem Informasi</option>
       </select>
   </div>
```

other divs

```
<div class="report" id="S1-Teknik_Informatika">
    <?php include 'searchs1if.php'; ?>
</div>
<div class="report" id="S1-Sistem_Informasi">
    <?php include 'search_s1si.php'; ?>
</div>
<div class="report" id="D3-Teknik_Informatika">
    <?php include 'searchd3if.php'; ?>
</div>
<div class="report" id="Program_Kompetensi">
    <?php include 'searchprokom.php'; ?>
</div>
```

The `<?php` part is irrelevant. All the PHP code is expanded on the server before the page is sent to the browser.

Comment: Thank u for ur jquery suggestion. It work. But like u said, the <?php is irrelevant, any idea to solve this..?

Comment: See my updated answer, it shows the fix more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces from `id's`.

```
<script>


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.report').hide();
        $('#prodi').change(function () {
        $('.report').hide();
            $(this).find("option").each(function () {
                //$('#' + this.value).hide(); // don't need 
            });
            $('#' + this.value).show();

        });
      });

  </script>
```

On load hide all the div through `.report` and after drop down values changes hide all the div again through `.report` and display the selected div.